# When we solve an equation, do we suppose that it is true and then work backward?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

A couple of days ago I was reading Calculus by James Stewart and I read this:

> Sometimes it is useful to imagine that your problem is solved and work backward, step
> by step, until you arrive at the given data. Then you might be able to reverse your steps
> and thereby construct a solution to the original problem. **This procedure is commonly
> used in solving equations. For instance, in solving the equation $3x - 5 = 7$, we suppose
> that $x$ is a number that satisfies $3x - 5 = 7$ and work backward.** We add $5$ to each side of the equation and then divide each side by $3$ to get $x = 4$. Since each of these steps
> can be reversed, we have solved the problem.

This sounded strange to me!
I have always thought that when we solve an equation we don't suppose that the equation is already satisfied. I have always thought that when we solve an equation we use algbraic property of numbers to obtain a simpler equation that is equivalent to the starting equation. And since the equations are equivalent we don't need to suppose that the initial equation is true, because when the last one is true, is true also the first one.

In other words: if I have to solve $3x - 5 = 7$ I don't need to suppose that $x$ is a number that satisys $3x - 5 = 7$, I simply ad $5$ to bothe sides to obtain the equivalent equation $3x = 12$, then I divide both sides by $3$ to obtain the equivalent equation $x = 4$, when the last one is true, is true also the first one and vice versa, the last one is true when $x$ is replaced by $4$, so $4$ is the solution.

And so this is my question: is it true that when we solve an equation we implicitly suppose that $x$ satisfies the equation (and we need to do that) to apply algebraic properties that give us the equivalent and simplier equation? Do we need this logic assumption in solving equations?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

Let me try to explain in a better way why I don't understand the need to suppose that $x$ satisfies the equation (i.e. that $x$ makes true the equality). Excuse me for the lenght of this edit.

Let's say I want to solve in $\mathbb{R}$ the equation $3x - 5 = 7$.
 I know that $$\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}, a + c = b + c \leftrightarrow a = b \tag{P1}$$ and I know that $$\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, (c \ne 0 \to (ac = bc \leftrightarrow a = b)) \tag{P2}$$ Property $\text{P1}$ says to me that:

- if $a + c = b + c$ is true, then $a = b$ is true;
- if $a = b$ is true, then $a + c = b + c$ is true;
- if $a + c = b + c$ is false, then $a = b$ is false;
- if $a = b$ is false, then $a + c = b + c$ is false;

and property $\text{P2}$ says to me that, if $c \ne 0$, then

- if $ac = bc$ is true, then $a = b$ ia true;
- if $a = b$ is true, then $ac =bc$ is true;
- if $ac = bc$ is false, then $a = b$ is false;
- if $a = b$ is false, then $ac =bc$ is false;

If I know all of this, then starting from $3x - 5 = 7$ I don't need to suppose that $x$ makes true the equality, because:

1. I can say that $3x - 5 = 7$ is equivalent to $3x = 12$ because of $\text{P1}$ without supposing that $3x - 5 = 7$ is true, they have the same truth value for the same value of $x$;
2. from $3x=12$, I can say that it is equivalent to $x = 4$ because of $\text{P2}$ without supposing that $3x = 12$ is true, they have the same truth value for the same value of $x$;
3. now I can say that $3x - 5 = 12$ is equivalent to $x = 4$ without supposing that $3x - 5 = 12$ is true, they have the same truth value for the same value of $x$;
4. in the end I have the solution, because when $x = 4$ is true, also $3x - 5 = 7$, so $4$ is the solution.

What am I doing wrong?
Why do I need to suppose that $x$ satisfy the equation?

Comment: What you say is the same Stewart does, it is just a matter of perpesctive.

Comment: You use the term "equivalent equation" while stewart says "... since each of these steps can be reversed..." so you're just using different wording to describe the same thing.

Comment: When you add $5$ to both sides, you're saying if $3x-5=7$ then $3x=12$.  That is, if $x$ satisfies the first equation, then it satisfies the second.  If you aren't supposing that $x$ satisfies the equation, what do these manipulations mean?

Comment: When we are solving an equation we are supposing that such a number exists. So when we solve $2x=4$ we are saying suppose there is a number $x$ that satisfies this equation. No one says that it actually exists yet.

Comment: @saulspatz Exactly. We have to suppose $x$ is a solution for the equation to make sense in the first place. To add: if we have something like $x + 1 = x$, we "solve" and get $1 = 0$. Did something go wrong? No, we just did a proof by contradiction. We supposed there was a solution $x$ and deduced a contradiction $1 = 0$. Thus $x + 1 = x$ has no solutions.

Comment: @DonAntonio I added an edit to my question.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I added an edit to my question.

Comment: @saulspatz I added an edit to my question.

Comment: @Anon I added an edit to my question.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins I added an edit to my question.

Comment: @user1988  What does $3x - 5 = 7$ mean if not "there is some value $x$ such that $3x - 5 = 7$"? This is not a rhetorical question. What do you take $3x - 5= 7$ to mean?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins $3x-5=7$ is a predicate. Its truth value depends on the value of $x$: if $x$ is $4$, then $3x-5=7$ is true and we say that $4$ satisfies the equation; if $x$ is another number, e.g. $0$, then $3x-5=7$ is false and we say that $0$ does not satisfy the equation. Solving an equation means to find the values that satisfy the equation, i.e. the values such that if $x$ is equal to one of these values, then the equality is true. Now: I can't understand why we need to suppose that $x$ satisfies the equation **before** starting to solve it. I can't understand it beacause of two reasons.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins First one: property $\text{P1}$ tells me that $3x-5=7$ is equivalent to $3x=12$; this means that when $3x-5=7$ is true also $3x=12$ is true and vice versa, and when $3x-5=7$ is false also $3x=12$ is false and vice versa; **this means that I don't need to suppose that $3x-5=7$ is true to transform it to $3x=12$**, because in $\text{P1}$ there is $\leftrightarrow$ between $a+c=b+c$ and $a=b$, if there had been $\to$ instead of $\leftrightarrow$, then I would have needed to suppose that $3x-5=7$ was true before starting to solve the equation and to switch from $3x-5=7$ to $3x=12$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Second one: proving that $3x-5=7$ is true is my goal, not my hypotesis; if I start supposing that $3x-5=7$ is true, then I'm supposing that my goal is true before to prove that it is true and this is wrong, because if I want to prove that $p \to q$, then I can't suppose that $q$ is already true, since this is exaclty what I have to prove, in this case $p$ is $x=4$ and $q$ is $3x-5=7$.

Comment: @user1988 I see. I think that way of thinking about things does work. I don't know if it's advisable, though. Many facts will only have implications in one direction. Additionally, many useful results are not formulated in terms of predicates with free variables, so it will require some extra work in some cases to show you can think about things this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we assume that $x$ satisfies the equation. Because if we transform the equation in equivalent ones and eventually reach $x=4$, that final equality also *assumes that $x$ satisfies it* (otherwise, $x=4$ would give you no information on the solutions of the equation).

Every step of the resolution handles equalities assumed to hold. But if at some stage you get an impossible equality, such as $1=4$, which is a *false* statement, then you know that none of the equalities is *true*, and no solution exists.

Comment: I added an edit to my question.

Comment: The coup de grâce, nearly always forgotten, is to substitute your answer into the original equation showing that it is in fact a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I see it as follows:

===  YOU SAY: Our company has found out that in order to maximize our profit the number of items sold, which we denote by $\;x\;$, must satisfy the equation $\;3x -5=7\;$ . Let's solve it to find the value of $\;x\;$ .

== STEWART SAYS: Our company has found out that in order to maximize our profit the number of items sold, which we denote by $\;x\;$, must satisfy the equation $\;3x -5=7\;$ . Let's assume such a value of $\;x\;$ exists and find its value.

After each of you say the above, you both do EXACTLY THE SAME: you, without assuming a value of $\;x\;$ exists, and Stewart assuming such a value exists...but the basic algebraic operations in both cases are exactly the same, they're just justified by slightly different arguments...which, if I'd worried a little more about this matter, I'd say I believe Stewart's reasoning is slightly sounder..

At the end, if you find something like say $\;x^2=-1\;$ in the real numbers, you'd say "Ok, that equation shows that my problem cannot be solved", whereas Stewart probably would say "Ok, that shows that assuming a solution exists to that equation leads us to a logical contradiction and thus the equation cannot be solved" (herein gets the law of excluded middle in the way, certainly).

Resuming: It seems to me more logical to begin by saying that the equation exists and it is so and so because we assume such a value of (real) $\;x\;$ exists that satisfies that equation than otherwise...and then everybody passes to solve the equation by the very exact steps in both cases (some doing a little more, some a little less).

By the end, in fact, the "checking" makes it clearer: substitution into the original eqaution. You may think mainly "Oh, this value $\;x=4\;$ ceratinly satisfies my equation", whereas Stewart perhaps would say "Ok, I found a real value for the equation I assumed $\;x\;$ satisfies and it is correct. Cool"...and both celebrate just the same.